# How to "bake" value in lambda

Tags: java, lambda

Let's say I have code like this

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface Callable {
    Integer multiply(Integer by);
}

class Builder {
    private Integer multiplier;

    public Builder multiplyBy(Integer multiplier) {
        this.multiplier= multiplier;
        return this;
    }

    public Callable build() {
        return (value) -> value * multiplier; //how to "bake" hever value
    }
}

// calling

Builder builder;
Callable multiplierBy3 = builder.multiplyBy(3);
Callable multiplierBy6 = builder.multiply(6);

multiplierBy3.multiply(10); //should return 30, returns 60
multiplierBy6.multiply(10); // return 60, ok, propably because of new multipier value
```

Behavior happens because calling second time `multiplyBy` sets new `value` in builder.
How I can manage to create each lambda own multiplier function?

Comment: Use two builders, that's where you're keeping the lambda state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [@Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman) said:

> Use two builders, that's where you're keeping the lambda state.

So the solution will be this way:

```java
Builder builderBy3 = new Builder();
Builder builderBy6 = new Builder();

Callable multiplierBy3 = builderBy3.multiplyBy(3).build();
Callable multiplierBy6 = builderBy6.multiplyBy(6).build();

System.out.println(multiplierBy3.multiply(10)); // Returns 30
System.out.println(multiplierBy6.multiply(10)); // Returns 60
```

But you can also do it modifying the `Builder`:

```java
class Builder {
    private Integer multiplier;

    public Builder multiplyBy(Integer multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
        return this;
    }

    public Callable build() {
        int currentMultiplier = this.multiplier; // Current multiplier value
        return (value) -> value * currentMultiplier; // Use it in the lambda
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```java
Builder builder = new Builder();

Callable multiplierBy3 = builder.multiplyBy(3).build();
Callable multiplierBy6 = builder.multiplyBy(6).build();

System.out.println(multiplierBy3.multiply(10)); // Returns 30
System.out.println(multiplierBy6.multiply(10)); // Returns 60
```

Comment: I was going to suggest your second suggestion myself. The local variable will not be updated when the builder's field is updated. It's effectively final, otherwise it can't even be used inside the lambda.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a closure.   When a value goes out of scope, the lambda still retains access to it. Using `Functional interfaces` or methods to convert `f(x,y)` to `f(x)(y)` is known as [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Note that you can use existing interfaces.

```
Function<Integer, UnaryOperator<Integer>> 
     createMultiplier = (operand1 -> operand2 -> operand1
         * operand2);
 
 Function<Integer, Integer> multiplyBy3 = createMultiplier.apply(3);
 Function<Integer, Integer> multiplyBy6 = createMultiplier.apply(6);
 
 int result1 = multiplyBy3.apply(10);
 int result2 = multiplyBy6.apply(20);
 
 System.out.println(result1);
 System.out.println(result2);
```

prints

```
30
120
```

Here is one I created some time ago for my own use. It allows the creation of a `log function` for any base.  I created an interface to give more appropriate names to the methods.

```
interface Log {   
    double of(double value);
    
    static Log forBase(double base) {
            // compute logBase once for given base
            final double logBase = Math.log(base);
            return value -> Math.log(value) / logBase;
    }
}
Log log2 = Log.forBase(2);
System.out.println(log2.of(32));
```

Or if you just need to get the log once.

```
 System.out.println(Log.forBase(2).of(32));
```

Both print

```
5.0
```